# How to write to HDFS using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I am learning Scala and i need to write a custom file to HDFS. I have my own HDFS running on a Cloudera image using vmware fusion on my laptop.

This is my actual code:

```
package org.glassfish.samples

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
* @author ${user.name}
*/
object App {

def main(args : Array[String]) {
println( "Trying to write to HDFS..." )
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs= FileSystem.get(conf)
val output = fs.create(new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/mySample.txt"))
val writer = new PrintWriter(output)
try {
    writer.write("this is a test") 
    writer.write("\n")
}
finally {
    writer.close()
}
print("Done!")
}

}
```

And i am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:588)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:439)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:426)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:775)
at org.glassfish.samples.App$.main(App.scala:19)
at org.glassfish.samples.App.main(App.scala)
... 6 more
```

I can access hdfs using the terminal and Hue

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /tmp
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2015-06-09 17:54 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
drwx-wx-wx   - hive     supergroup          0 2015-08-17 15:24 /tmp/hive
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2015-08-17 16:50 /tmp/labdata
```

this is my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/HgA5eNYD)

I ran the project using the command:

mvn clean package scala:run

What do i am doing wrong? thank you in advance!

EDIT after @jeroenr advice

This is actual code:

```
package org.glassfish.samples

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
* @author ${user.name}
*/
object App {

//def foo(x : Array[String]) = x.foldLeft("")((a,b) => a + b)

def main(args : Array[String]) {
println( "Trying to write to HDFS..." )
val conf = new Configuration()
//conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020")
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.30.147:8020")
val fs= FileSystem.get(conf)
val output = fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))
val writer = new PrintWriter(output)
try {
    writer.write("this is a test") 
    writer.write("\n")
}
finally {
    writer.close()
    println("Closed!")
}
println("Done!")
}

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at this [this example here](http://midgetontoes.com/blog/2014/10/04/scala-write-files-to-hadoop-hdfs). I think the problem is that you don't configure the default file system using

```
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020")
```

and pass the relative path, like so:

```
fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))
```

to write to the file, call 'write' directly on the output stream returned by *fs.create*, like so:

```
val os = fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))
os.write("This is a test".getBytes)
```

Comment: Hi @jeroenr, thank you for the advice. After the patch i can see the new file in hdfs but without content, weird isn't ? I can see the messages Closed and Done on terminal.

Comment: It must be related with the port. I have seen in your example that you are using 9000 port. I have tried with that port but i get a ConnectException:Connection refused. It is not 8020 port nor 9000, what port can be? Seeing this url is useless http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/

Comment: @aironman I don't know about the port, but I believe you should call 'write' directly on the return value of 'fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))'. So:

val output = fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))
output.write("this is a test").getBytes

Comment: @aironman According to http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/PDF/cloudera-quickstart.pdf default port is 7180

Comment: https://midgetontoes.com/blog/2014/10/04/scala-write-files-to-hadoop-hdfs/ is now a dead link.

Comment: In my case, I had to call `.close()` to perform the write. Neither `.hflush()` nor `.hsync()` performed the write to remote location.

Comment: One question, does anyone know an asynchronous library for writing data to HDFS?