# How to store the result of an action in apache spark using scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

How to store the result generated from an action like: count in an output directory, in apache Spark Scala?

```
    val countval= data.map((_,"")).reduceByKey((_+_)).count
```

The below command does not work as count is not stored as RDD:

```
    countval.saveAsTextFile("OUTPUT LOCATION")
```

Is there any way to store countval into local/hdfs location?

Comment: See  [How to write to a file in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4604237/1560062) and [Write a file in hdfs with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java) and [How to write to HDFS using Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380272/how-to-write-to-hdfs-using-scala)

Comment: Maybe he wants to use a Scala library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what @szefuf said is correct, after `count` you have a `Long` which you can save any way you want. 
If you want to save it as an `RDD` with `.saveAsTextFile()` you have to convert it to an RDD:

```
 sc.parallelize(Seq(countval)).saveAsTextFile("/file/location")
```

The `parallelize` method in SparkContext turns a collection of values into an RDD, so you need to turn the single value to a single-element sequence first. Then you can save it.

Answer (score 1):

After you call `count` it is no longer RDD.

Count is just `Long` and it does not have `saveAsTextFile` method.

If you want to store your `countval` you have to do it like with any other long, string, int...