# How to write a string to a text file in HDFS?

Tags: scala

I have a string which I want to override and write a an hdfs text file in Scala. Below is the code I am currently using.

```
import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, FileOutputStream}

val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration); 
val filename = "hdfs://<IP>:9000/path/to/save/mytext.conf"
val textout = fs.create(new Path(filename));

val value1 = 23
val value2 = 25

val os = java.io.BufferedOutputStream(textout)
os.write(("key1: " + value1 + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"))
os.write(("key2: " + value2 + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"))

os.close()
```

Unfortunately, the above code gives me the following error:

```
<console>:146: error: object java.io.BufferedOutputStream is not a value
       val os = java.io.BufferedOutputStream(textout)
                        ^
```

How to save my key value pairs in a text file in HDFS in Scala?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to HDFS using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380272/how-to-write-to-hdfs-using-scala)

Comment: `val os = java.io.BufferedOutputStream(textout)` should be `val os = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(textout)` you don't need `new` for case classes because `apply` in the companion object is delegating to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val array = Array("Key1: 23", "Key2: 25")
sc.parallelize(array).repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/myconf")
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation about what the problem is and how this code helps.