# Writing records to hdfs when catch exception in filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which I have to filter .However, In filter spark is getting connected to database. If database to connection failed I have to write that row to hdfs

```
    //filteredRawDf is dataframe
    val filteredRawDf = dfToReingest.filter { rawRow =>
      // getting.database object to connect 
      val databaseClient = getDataBaseClient(config)

      //getting primary key from row
      val requestNumber = rawRow.getAs[Row]("Column1").getAs[String]("Subcolumn")

      // if primary key is present then it will return record otherwise null
      val requestNumber_srs = databaseClient.getRecord(requestNumber)

      requestNumber_srs == null
    }
```

if databse is down then it will through exception . We have to get Rows if exception is thrown and save it to hdfs .

Answer (score 0):

I can think about two options (If i understood your problem currectly):

1. Add _currupted_record column to schema and then surrend your filter code with try catch, if exception is thrown so make row[_currupted_record ]=true and return true (you need the record not being dropped by filter), then filter all the _currupted_record=true records and write them to HDFS.
2. Surrend your filter code with try catch, if exception is thrown write the rawRow to HDFS via JAVA HDFS FileSystem and return false.
   You can look here how to write file to HDFS with FileSystem api ([How to write to HDFS using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380272/how-to-write-to-hdfs-using-scala))