# object SparkHadoopUtil in package deploy cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.deploy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-shell

Why SparkHadoopUtil is not accessible here whereas is accessible in lower version of spark even though they are imported?

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.2
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_282)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

scala> 

scala> 

scala>  val hadoopConf: Configuration = SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf
<console>:25: error: object SparkHadoopUtil in package deploy cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.deploy
        val hadoopConf: Configuration = SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf
                                        ^

scala>
```

Comment: You get the conf from sparkContext:  `val hadoopConf: Configuration = sc.hadoopConfiguration`

Comment: Did you figure this out? Running into same issue when migration from 2.4 to 3.1

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `SparkHadoopUtil` class has been changed to a private class in Spark 3. Here's the difference between the source of [Spark 2.4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L50) and [Spark 3.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L47).

Spark 2.4:

```
@DeveloperApi
class SparkHadoopUtil extends Logging {
```

Spark 3.0:

```
private[spark] class SparkHadoopUtil extends Logging {
```

Comment: Thanks @mck , but in that case is there a work around for it as i was using it for getting the file system as `FileSystem.get(SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf)`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32380272). You can try: `import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` `val conf = new Configuration()` `val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)`

Comment: `new Configuration()` is not completly correct for the hadoop conf config by `--conf` @mck